# Lua - How to check if list contains element

Tags: arrays, list, lua, element

I need some help with my lua script for a game. I need to check if my inventory in the game contains any id from a list.

Here's a piece of my list:

```
local Game_Items = {
    {id = 7436, name = "angelic axe", value = 5000},
    {id = 3567, name = "blue robe", value = 10000},
    {id = 3418, name = "bonelord shield", value = 1200},
    {id = 3079, name = "boots of haste", value = 30000},
    {id = 7412, name = "butcher's axe", value = 18000},
    {id = 3381, name = "crown armor", value = 12000}
}
```

The following code might look a bit weird since you don't know what it's for, but it's basically this: the list above is a list of items in my game, and inside the game theres an inventory where you can keep items and stuff. Now I want to check if my inventory contains any of those IDs.

I tried adding 2 of the id's manually and it worked, but my list of items contains over 500 items in total and I don't want to write them all out. Is there a way to put the whole list and check if it's in there somehow?

```
if not table.contains({ 3035, 3043, Game_Items[id] }, tempItemCounter.id) then
```

This is what I tried so far. Those two first id's work 3035 and 3043, then I tried all my whole list and only check the Ids. but I dont know how to do that. That code does not work. Could anyone just help me include the whole list of id's in the table.contains ?

Basically wanna include my whole list in that line, without typing out all IDs manually.
Shouldn't Game_Items[id] work? Doesn't that mean all the "id" inside "Game_Items"?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show what your inventory looks like, or is it same structure as `Game_Items`? Also, can you change the structure of both to be a map instead of array, like `Game_Items = { [7346] = {name="...", value=5000}, [3567] = {name = ....}, ...}`? Because if you can't you're going to have to loop over every inventory item for each game item. Finally, do you want to know if inventory contains all items, so if even one item is missing the test should be false?

Answer (score 1):

No it doesn't mean that. If foo is a table, then foo[id] looks for a field in foo that is called whatever id refers to, such as a string (so if id is 1 you will get foo[1], if id is "bar" you will get foo.bar, etc).

You can't do it in one line, but you can create a function that will allow you to write your if condition. I'm not sure what `tempItemCounter` is but assuming that your inventory is a map of keys to entries of the form

```
inventory = {
    [1234] = {....}, 
    [1235] = {....},
    ...
}
```

where each integer key is unique, and assuming you want true only if all items are in inventory, then you could do this:

```
function isAllInInventory(items, inventory)
    for i,item in ipairs(items) do
         if inventory[item.id] == nil
              return false
         end
    end
    return true
end

if isAllInInventory(Game_Items, inventory) then
    ...
end
```